# Is it possible to send native system input to a java application?

Tags: java, c++, c, winapi

I know I can use the Robot class in Java to generate native system input but is it possible to do the same for a Java application using C/C++ and the Windows SDK?

I'm not sure how Java registers stuff like that but perhaps it uses Windows messages or Raw Input?

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Most likely window messages. Raw input is done through a `WM_INPUT` message as well.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365088/giving-input-to-a-gui-application-through-another-program/12365696#12365696